# How to do form validation with Django?

Tags: python, django, forms, security

This is a simple form that is present in my template(comment.html).

```
<form id="my_form" action="{% url 'a' pk=id %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input id="in" required minlength="5" name="message" type="text"><br>
            <button id="click" title="add your comment" type="submit">Comment</button>
</form>
```

As you can see there is an input tag inside form whose name is "message".My problem is that when user get this page on his/her computer as a response means they can simply see this form code on their browser. Let assume a user changed the value of the name attribute of input tag and submit the form then I don't get the value of 'message'.

Can you tell me how i can write a view to validate my form on the server-side? So that my website stays safe from a malicious user and from a hacker?

Answer (score 0):

Let assume a user changed the value of the name attribute of input tag such as:

```
    <input id="in" required minlength="5" name="message" type="text"><br>
```

to:

```
    <input id="in" minlength="500" name="hacked_message" type="text"><br>
```

**Yes, you will not get the value of message for that *particular user***, why would you want someone's message if they are malicious ?

But you will get the value of message for other users who don't manipulate their code.

Comment: Then how is the stack-overflow is working? When I change the name attribute of the input tag in the stack-overflow site in their comment section my comment get published, how this thing work I want to know.

Comment: ok did you change the comment name by doing inspect element and changing name of this textarae ?

Comment: yes you are right. i did my comment got saved but how.

Comment: because stack-overflow, is not depending on name attribute maybe, maybe they use #id instead. if you look, in the console(XHR tab). there will a post request for each comment made, click on Params, it will show what excatly was send to server. this is mainly done using ajax,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the django forms.
Here you have the link for the documentation about that :
[Django Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/)

Why use django forms ?

Because you have methods that you can use in your view like this :

```
form.is_valid()
```

Quick example here:
[form validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#the-view)

And here, your have more informations about is_valid() method:
[is_valid() doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_valid)

Comment: is_valid() method only valid form data, not form attributes and their values .thanks for the answer.